# SIGSEGV in QAbstractSocket::writeData when writing 5k of data

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qtnetwork

Working on an ARM system and I'm getting a SIGSEGV in QAbstractSocket::writeData(char const*, long long). I'm calling it via QIODevice::write(char const*, long long) and it's a moderately small amount of data. Just 5k.

I'm checking that the memory that is being sent is correctly allocated with new[] and that the QIODevice is open before sending. Smaller packets work reliably but the exact threshold of when the packets are too large appears to vary. I'd binary searched it down to find it was just under 4k but then when running the code in gdb it rose a bit but I didn't binary search to find where exactly.

There is plenty of ram spare, I can increase the packet size to well over 1M and the new[] is still happy.

The Qt version is 4.8.6.

I'd rather not reveal the entire back trace from the project, it reveals more details of the project than I'd like to. But the top few frames are:

```
#0  0xb6b6ed6c in __memcpy_neon () at ../ports/sysdeps/arm/armv7/multiarch/memcpy_impl.S:596  
#1  0xb6f71dce in QAbstractSocket::writeData(char const*, long long) () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQtNetwork.so.4  
#2  0xb6d9b5fe in QIODevice::write(char const*, long long) () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQtCore.so.4
```

Any ideas on what is going wrong?

Comment: There are many buffers in the networking layers between your program and the physical signaling, maybe some buffer in a lower layer isn't big enough? Trying to write so much at once is kind of pointless anyway, since it won't fit in a single network packet and has to be broken-up/reassembled by the network stacks.

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem with a short program and post that. This would make it much easier to give a correct answer. As of now, I would guess that either your pointer is invalid or the size argument is incorrect (e.g. larger than the memory the pointer points to).

Comment: Show some code. You don't need to show your actual code, post a small program that reproduces your error.

Comment: Check with Valgrind.

Comment: Thank you Joachim, Rumburak and Gj13.
Velkan: It'd be great if Valgrind worked in things that were x86.

Comment: Valgrind supports arm up to armv7 http://valgrind.org/info/platforms.html

Comment: Where did I get that 'knowledge' from, hrm. Will play more :)

Comment: Closing question as bug was extra dereference of buffer, nothing to do with what I asked here.